# Justifying text in overleaf template

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I really want to use the following overleaf template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/sample-apa-paper/wbzdqpgxszqs#.WRby39zfPIV
(Sample APA paper)
But unfortunately, the text is left rigged and I want it to be justified. 
I assumed that justified text is latex's default, so I concluded that in this template leftrigged must be on but I cannot find it.
Does someone know a solution?

Comment: Welcome, that isn't a template, it is an example by someone. Even if it would be a template, there would be no warranty for it to work or beeing correct.

Comment: You want to write a document according to the rules of the american psychological association?

Comment: oh I'm sorry, it said template on the link, so I just took that expression.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes, exactly and I like the exact layout of the example, so I would want to use it but I need a justified layout

Comment: Check the rules, APA defines a ragged text. You can try package `ragged2e` and the command `\justifying` to get an almost APA document.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

APA guidelines require ragged papers. If you want your text to be justified, you will not get a document complying to APA rules, but a close hit.

Add to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
```

Comment: Should provide details as in reply from Nazehs below.

Answer (score 12):

Add `\usepackage{ragged2e}` to the preamble and use `\justify{ text }` wherever you want to justify the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This answer is probably problematic for whole documents (not for pieces of text). Maybe you could add a general explanation.

Comment: `justify`  is an environment, not a command.

Comment: @Johannes_B This somehow worked for me, while your answer did not do anything.

Comment: Sorry this answer is wrong `\justify`  should be used as `\begin{justify}` and if used as in this answer it will apply to the rest of the document not just `{ text }`

Answer (score 10):

import the below on the preamble section

`\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}`

targeted text goes here...

`\begin{justify}`

text goes here...

`\end{justify}`

or you can use below to apply to the blocks/text after the command

`\justify`

Answer (score 0):

1. The following code insert a tabulation at the beginning of the text

   `\justifying` or `\justifying{ text }`
2. The following code justify both sides (no tabulation)

   `justify`