# Mysterious blank page appears before front page when changing to twoside this overleaf book class template

Tags: formatting, templates, overleaf, blank-page, front-matter

I am customizing [this overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-kwazulu-natal-thesis-template-by-publication/wcgjvskbmgxy) for my thesis but I want it two sided. However, if I change oneside to twoside in the book class there is a mysterious first page appearing before the front page, with the number 2 at the bottom. Putting

```
\cleardoublepage
```

before including the front page doesn't work. The solution given by @Werner [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140329/61576), that is, to include

```
usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
```

in the preamble, also doesn't work. Increasing the margin inside geometry package settings doesn't work. What can I do? Any help is much appreciated.

As requested by David, I manage to get the very minimal version of the template and the problem comes from the use of `\justify` from the `ragged2e` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\justify
\begin{titlepage}
      ...TITLE PAGE...
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apologize @DavidCarlisle, I added a small code with the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: actually I was a bit harsh to say no information given you had the link, but still pointing to the external template isn't the most helpful form:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\justify` is like `\center` and should never be used in the command form, they are the internal implementations of `\begin{justify}` and `\begin{center}`.

The declaration form is `\justifying` (but should almost never be needed as justification is the default. However `\justifying` does not cause the extra page.

Comment: That was indeed a misuse of \justifying. This is a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369549/justifying-text-in-overleaf-template

Answer (score 1):

Using `\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}`

(1) Comment `%\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}`

(2) Do not use `\justify`

```
\begin{document}
%\justify
%frontmatter
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty} %disable headers and footers
\pagenumbering{roman} %use roman page numbering in the frontmatter

\input{frontmatter/frontpage}
```

Comment: Thanks for having looked into the template! :-)